# .SaveChanges() not saving to data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I see this question has been asked before but I am still completely stumped on why this object is not being saved to the database. I am using two service methods to populate a table.  CreateFirstCategory() works correctly and saves to the database but for some reason CreateFirstItem() will initialize the new object but will not save it to the database. Any ideas why?

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Programming_Library.Data;
using Programming_Library.Models;
using Programming_Library.Services;

namespace Programming_Library.Controllers
{
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ICreateService _createService;

        public DashboardController(ApplicationDbContext context, ICreateService createService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _createService = createService;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _createService.CreateFirstCategory();
            _createService.CreateFirstItem();



            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
using Programming_Library.Data;
using Programming_Library.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Programming_Library.Services
{
    public class CreateService : ICreateService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public CreateService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Category> CreateFirstCategory()
        {
            var categoryCount = _context.Category.Count();
            if (categoryCount == 0)
            {
                var category = new Category
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Instructions",
                };
                await _context.Category.AddAsync(category);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return category;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<Item> CreateFirstItem()
        {
            int itemCount = _context.Item.Count();
            if (itemCount == 0)
            {
                var item = new Item
                {
                    CategoryId = 0,
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Getting Started",
                    Updated = DateTime.Now,
                };
                await _context.Item.AddAsync(item);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return item;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Programming_Library.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            Sections = new HashSet<Section>();
        }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTimeOffset Updated { get; set; }

        public string PLUserID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int languageId { get; set; }
        public int FrameworkId { get; set; }
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }

        public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
        public Framework Framework { get; set; }
        public language language { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Async Tasks CreateFirstCategory and CreateFirstItem. They are being created and ran concurrently. You need a way to verify that one of the Async tasks is finished before the second runs.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I made them into synchronous methods and now there is no thread conflictions.

Answer (score 3):

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    _createService.CreateFirstCategory();
    _createService.CreateFirstItem();


    return View();
}
```

and

```
public async Task<Category> CreateFirstCategory()
public async Task<Item> CreateFirstItem()
```

Your `Create` methods are async, but your controller is not.  The code is not getting awaited and the method and processing ends before the items are created.  You need to add `await` to your `Create` calls:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     await _createService.CreateFirstCategory();
     await _createService.CreateFirstItem();

     return View();
}
```